# Laravel 5.5 - mail not working with `mail` driver

Tags: php, email, php-7, swiftmailer, laravel-5.5

Ob my Laravel setup, mail was always working until I upgraded the framework to `5.5` (from 5.4). Now it always fail at the following:

[image]

Do note the following:

1. mail server on local env = http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/users-manual.html ive used this like since 5yrs (this is a one-click-install/no-dramas/no-config/no-error test mail server) and till yesterday it worked so im NOT changing it to something else
2. The php's `mail()` function works if called directly
3. The mail driver ive set is just `mail` however it still goes here to `sendmail` (you can vardump the $command and it says `/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs`)

Here is the `.env` for mail:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

So does anyone knows how to solve this? It only starred in laravel 5.5

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you provide the .env config with the MAIL_* lines and the code where you call the Mail function ?

Comment: ive added that to the question now, please check thanks

Comment: If you are using php's mail() function directly instead of Laravel's Mail facade then you probably have to set your mail driver properties in php.ini file instead of .env file.

Comment: I said `IF` i use `mail()` directly (i.e. as a test). Otherwise im using Mail facade.

Answer (score 8):

Found the reason and hence had to find an alternate solution.

[Reason]: **Swiftmailer no longer supports `mail` transport**

(See here)

https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/866

https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/3256

**[Solution]:**
Use `smtp` instead of `mail`.

Comment: And the reason why Swiftmailer removed the mail driver is that PHP's `mail()` function is insecure. Read https://blog.ripstech.com/2017/why-mail-is-dangerous-in-php/

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to use the `smtp driver`, you can use `'sendmail'` instead of `'mail'`.  Just make sure `proc_open()` **is enabled** on your server though.